# Brachah on Tying Tefillin knots

Tags: blessing, tefilin

Is there a *brachah* that should be said before tying knots on the *tefillin shel yad* and *rosh*, similar to way there is in Gemara a *brachah* before tying *tzitzis*? (The *brachah* is ברוך אתה ה' אלקינו מלך העולם, אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו לעשות ציצת, also you say לשם מצות ציצת)

Comment: Where did you learn about this Berakha? I've never seen anyone say it before. Is it in any Siddurim that you know of? Please [edit] your post to clarify how you know that is the correct Berakha to make in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `there is a brachah before tying tzitzis? (The brachah is ברוך אתה ה' אלקינו מלך העולם, אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו לעשות ציצת`

It seems from the Gemara in Menachot 42a that this Bracha is not ruled (this Beracha is said according to Rav Chisda who stated that Tsitsit Chovat Talit (an obligation resting upon the garment).) because we stated as Rav Nachman that Tsitsit is Chovat Gavra (an obligation incumbent upon the person). But concerning Tefilin there is no Machloket that it is an obligation incumbent upon the person and the Mitsva is not ended before the Hanacha.

> R' Nahman once found R'Adda B'Ahabah inserting the threads [in a
> garment] and reciting the blessing '[Blessed art thou.
>
> and hast commanded us] to make the zizith', whereupon he said, 'What
> is this zizi that I hear?
>
> Thus said Rab: **When making the zizith no blessing is to be
> pronounced'**.
>
> 42b: Over the hand-tefillah one must say, 'Blessed.
>
> who hast sanctified us by thy commandments and hast commanded us to
> put on the tefillin'.
>
> Over the head-tefillah one must say, 'Blessed.
>
> who hast sanctified us by thy commandments and hast given us command
> concerning the precept of the tefillin'.
>
> But one never says, '[Blessed.
>
> and hast commanded us] to make the tefillin!' - Indeed this is the
> true principle: Wherever a precept is completed by a single act,
>
> Rambam, Ahava, Brachot, 11, 8:
>
> **Whenever the performance of a mitzvah constitutes the completion of
> one's obligation**, he should recite the blessing before performing it.
> **When, however, there is another commandment that follows the
> performance of a particular mitzvah**, the blessing should not be
> recited until the other mitzvah is performed.
>
> What is implied? When a person makes a sukkah, a lulav, a shofar,
> tzitzit (see [SA OC 19, 1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x372)), tefillin, or a mezuzah, he should not recite a blessing at
> the time he made [them]: [praising God for] "sanctifying us with Your
> commandments and commanding us to make a sukkah" or "a lulav," or "to
> write tefillin," because there is another commandment that follows
> this action.
>
> When is the blessing recited? When one sits in the sukkah, shakes the
> lulav, hears the sounding of the shofar, wraps oneself in tzitzit,
> dons tefillin, or affixes the mezuzah. In contrast, when one
> constructs a guardrail, before constructing it one should recite the
> blessing "...who has sanctified us with Your commandments and
> commanded us to construct a guardrail." The same applies in all
> similar situations.

#### summary: because there is another commandment that follows  this action, we don't blessing on tying tefilin knots.

Answer (score 0):

We do not follow the Yerushalmi who posits making the *brochoh* you quote on making the *tsitsis*. Thus, similarly, there is no *brocho* said on making the knots of *Tefillin* - just to say לשם קדושת תפילין

Comment: What about when U complete a Rams horn for a shofer??? Why don't we say ״לשם מצוות קול שופר״ ???

Comment: @DavidFeigen A Shofar doesn't need to be made Lishmah.